# Good fonts for a webpage

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts

I am making a modern web page and I cannot find any websites that will lead me to fonts that are available on google, may someone please suggest some google fonts for a modern design web page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try Google Fonts, [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto/) and [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato/) are very popular, but there are many other options. Look into the [Sans Serif](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans%20Serif) category. Most of these are quality fonts and free to use commercially.

[image]